# What equation describes the matter field in an electrostatic potential?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I study mathematics at a university, and one of my courses is physics, the course goal being to introduce mathematical methods used in physics to us math students. I got puzzled by one of the problems in my latest assignment in that course and hope to get a clarification here. In short, the problem comprises a set of mathematical questions about a physical equation I don't even know about, and I have no idea where I can find that equation in order to start solving the problem.

Here's the formulation of the problem:

> The field of charged matter $\Psi (x,t)$, whose mass parameter is
> $\kappa$, is interacting with the potential of a static electric field
> $\phi(x)$. The parameter of this interaction is $\epsilon$. Write down
> the wave equation for that field. By using the WKB method, find its
> solution that corresponds to oscillations with a frequency $\omega$.
> What conditions on the potential must be fulfilled for this approach
> to be valid? Find the wave vector of the field as a function of the
> coordinate. What is the group velocity of the wave packet in the
> vicinity of this frequency and the coordinate of the center of the
> packet?

What is the wave equation the problem is about? If I knew it, I could derive answers to all other questions of this problem myself, as I know what the WKB method is and how to calculate the group velocity and other stuff.

Unfortunately, the physics lectures became practically impossible to follow, and no one of my fellow students who I talked with knows the answer to the question I am asking here. The lecture notes distributed by the lecturer are too succinct and messy to be of any help with this problem. The closest things I could find there seem to be the Klein-Gordon equation and its modification for the case of presence of an electromagnetic field:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{c^2 \partial t^2} = - \kappa \Psi  + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4c^2}A_4^2 \Psi + \bigtriangledown^2 \Psi - i \epsilon \left(  \overleftarrow{A} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \overleftarrow{x}} \right) \Psi$$

Interestingly, the formulation of the next problem in the assignment states that "the matter field of a charged particle moving in an electric field with a potential $A_4 = \phi(x)$ that smoothly varies in space is modeled by the modified Klein-Gordon equation," and explicitly provides that equation:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Psi(x,t)}{c^2 \partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \Psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2} - \frac{c^2 m^2}{\hbar^2} \Psi(x,t)  + \frac{e^2 \phi^2(x)}{c^2 \hbar^2}\Psi(x,t) - 2i \frac{e \phi(x)}{c\hbar} \frac{\partial \Phi(x,t)}{c \partial t}$$

My wild guess is that I should simply take this equation, take $\kappa = c^2m^2/\hbar^2$ and $\epsilon = 2 e/\hbar$, and use the resulting equation to solve the former problem, but it seems weird that the formulation of a problem asks something that is essentially answered by the formulation of the next problem. Is my guess correct, or what equation should I use to solve the former problem?

Update: Thanks a lot for the comments. I assumed my guess was correct, and used it. I got a very high grade for the assignment so I guess I did what the lecturer wanted me to do.

Comment: MY guess would be that they want you to write down the Lagrangian for a scalar field which is free other than its minimal coupling to the vector potential. Once you have the Lagrangian, it's simple to obtain the EoM.

Comment: It’s odd to call a massive charged scalar field “matter” since we know of no actual matter described by a charged scalar field.

Comment: it is impossible to say which matter your professor meant without asking them. It can be KG (like you gave in your question), or Dirac. If you didn’t cover the Dirac equation yet, KG is a safe bet.